# Symbol to signify the root of a project

Tags: java, node.js, windows, unix, filesystems

Is there a well accepted symbol in the programming world for the root of a project?

For example, the tilde ~ is the user's home directory, but this not just convention, but part of UNIX.

I am looking for a symbol that is merely convention.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a convention for use in communicating with a team, I'd suggest the project name followed by a `/`. This makes it clear as to what project you are referring to. If the project name is already implied by the context, it seems to be the convention to simply use a subdirectory name, with or without a trailing slash. See [here](http://www.mulix.org/lectures/tau_linux_workshop/kernel_src_intro.pdf) and [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/sources/sources.html) for examples from Linux-kernel related documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any such convention. In [Autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html), variables `top_srcdir` and `abs_top_srcdir` points to the root of a project. In [git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse), this does the job:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

However, if you are looking for a *single character symbol*, I suggest borrowing the *tee* character: ⊤ (U+22A4, &#8868). I don't think it has ever been used for that, but it captures the idea of *top*.

Answer (score 2):

> the root of a project

What means the root of the project exactly ? Given which context ? Which types of projects ? Are you talking about a deployed web projects ? A source tree of a web projects ? A command line utility written in C ? Or in Java ? Or Go ?

Each language and framework provides its on sets of predefined structures to follow. The root of the project is then, either the root of the vcs, which may store many assets not strictly related to the business of the software, or the root according to the given framework / language you are working with, in which case, i assume it is safe to say, it can be anything because they are so many different fw for so many different concerns.

Answer (score 2):

## Windows vs. POSIX

The Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX) like UNIX.

Windows has `C://` or other drivers as root, while POSIX have `/` as root.

to know if the file is a root path or not, you can use `path.isAbsolute('PATH_HERE')` this ill return true if it is a root path.

to know if your node is running on a windows or POSIX platform use `process.platform`

to check if you are running in windows:

`var isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform);`

nodeJS Docs: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/path.html#path_path_isabsolute_path

Answer (score 1):

i think people usually use label to be the root instead of symbol, e.g., /server for the root of node app.

Answer (score 1):

## The Be-all, End-all

After doing the bare minimum of research and reading about 1/4 of a wikipedia article on [Root Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory) I have come to the almighty, forever-binding conclusion that:

> No, there is no standardized way of indicating you are in the root directory of an arbitrary project. (Apart from reading the path itself)

Here is [another link](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/13w/notes/450_file_system.html) pertaining to inodes farther down  to make it seem like I did more research.

### In that case, making a standard seems like fun doesn't it?

The standard you come up with doesn't have to be global, it can just apply to your dev team if you want it to. In that case, let's make 3 right off the top of our (my) head.

How about `|->foo/bar/a.java`? The `|` indicates a flat level, with nothing before it.

We could always try a boring (but useful... I guess): `(foo)/bar/a.java`

Or to spice things up a little bit, we could do...

`I am gROOT
      |foo|/bar/a.java`

Whatever standard you choose (which is kinda funny, because the usage of standard implies that there's only one) you're now going to have to...

### Implement it!

This is going to be the hard part. You're going to have to find some way to indicate to the OS that you're not only in an arbitrary directory, but that you're in a directory that holds *slightly more* significance than others. Maybe you add another section to the INODE (in *nix at least) that specifies that it's important. *Maybe* you don't fuss around with all the OS level stuff, and instead patch git to recognize the root of all git projects... which now that I think about it, kind of already happens.

### Possible Implementation

Lets use git as an example. Git projects are denoted by `.git` files in the root directory. So let's take that a step farther and put a `.base` file in every directory that is the root of a project (or what have you). The `.base` doesn't even need to have anything in it, it just needs to be there. Now, patch up whatever terminal you're using to recognize the `.base` file as the root of an arbitrary project, and display it however you like! EZ-PZ

### Possible additions?

Some other thoughts here, maybe you could add some configuration to the `.base` file, like so:

```
proj_name=WorldTraveller
lang=java
other=stuff
can=go
here=whatever
```

which then drives how its displayed in the terminal. The above configuration using my first suggested standard would be

`|->WorldTraveller/Countries/France/a.java`

#### Note

I'm not trying to come off as a sarcastic D.i.a.B, so if I came off as one it wasn't my intention. I like to have fun answering questions sometimes.

Comment: Upwoted for the steam and solution-oriented creativity, fits my head.